# To set focus on textbox if the condition is failure using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In the below code i have a textbox and a javascript function which has regular expression.I can validate regular expressions in textbox it will alert success or failure.My aim is if it is failure it should focus on textbox and should not able to move to another control until it is success.
js:

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {

        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

        var iReturn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length - 1; i++) {

            var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            if (!txtInput.match(re)) {
                iReturn = iReturn + 1;
            }
        }

        if (iReturn > 0) {
        alert("Failed...");

           }
        else {
            alert("Success...");

        }

    }
```

asp.net:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtField" runat="server" width="200Px" onfocus="But1()"></asp:TextBox>
```

codebehind

```
 txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(document.getElementById('" + txtField.ClientID + "').value, '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are already using `onblur` event so you just need to use javascript `focus()` to set focus on your text box. I have changed your code to pass `this`(your control) to javascript function.

Change you code behind code to

```
txtField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "javascript:ValidateRegExp(this, '" + hidRegExp.Value + "');");
```

and your javascript code to

```
function ValidateRegExp(txtInput, REGEXP) {

        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = REGEXP.split("~~");

        var iReturn = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length - 1; i++) {

            var re = new RegExp(mySplitResult[i]);
            if (!txtInput.value.match(re)) {
                iReturn = iReturn + 1;
            }
        }

        if (iReturn > 0) {
        alert("Failed...");
         txtInput.focus(); //set focus back to control.
           }
        else {
            alert("Success...");

        }

    }
```